# Distinguish between wl_surface, wl_shell_surface and cairo_surface

Tags: surface, wayland

Could you please help me to make differences among those surface.
What is a top/parent surface ?
How to create and destroy each surface in order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wl_surface is a rectangular area that is displayed on the screen. It has a location, size and pixel contents. The backend compositor (weston) does know it.

A wl_shell is a interface that implemented by a wl_surface, provides a desktop-style user interface.

a cairo_surface is interface (rectangular area) to draw 2D Objects on wayland surface.

[image]